# Regex select text excluding certain characters

Tags: c#, regex

I have a text like this

```
MyText.xyz;
MyText.abc + "ss";
```

I want to capture text which comes after `MyText.`, but does not end with `;` or empty space, i.e. I want the output like:

```
MyText.xyz
MyText.abc
```

I have created this regex: `MyText.(.*(?=\;))` in order to achieve my goal.

But, right now the text matching out from regex is `MyText.xyz` and `MyText.abc + "ss"`, i.e. the second result is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

You may fix it using a negated character class:

```
MyText\.[^\s;]+
        ^^^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=MyText%5C.%5B%5E%5Cs%3B%5D%2B&i=MyText.xyz%3B%0D%0AMyText.abc%20%2B%20%22ss%22%3B)

**Regex details**

- `MyText\.` - a literal `MyText.` substring (note the `.` must be escaped to match a literal `.` char)
- `[^\s;]+` - a negated character class matching any 1+ chars other than whitespace (`\s`) and `;` char

Use it as `var pattern = @"MyText\.[^\s;]+";` in C#.

Answer (score 1):

```
MyText\..+?\b(?<!;)
   ^  ^ ^  ^  ^
   |__|_|__|__|______ MyText : "MyText" literal
      |_|__|__|______ \.     : "." literal, escaped by "\"
        |__|__|______ .      : any character
           |__|______ ?\b    : non-greedy search up to boundary (\b)
              |______ (?<!;) : not ended by ';'
```

Test:

```
$ cat sample.txt
MyText.xyz;
MyText.abc + "ss";
MyText.uuu+"yyy";

$ grep -Po 'MyText\..+?\b(?<!;)' <sample.txt
MyText.xyz
MyText.abc
MyText.uuu
```

Note: It's based on solution of @Wiktor Stribiżew, with looking behind added

Comment: I like your explanation, ASCII ftw!

Answer (score 0):

You are using

```
MyText.(.*(?=\;))
```

The first mistake is the `.` after `MyText`, it should be `\.` if you want to match a literal dot.

The second half is also incorrect, you're trying to match any number of non-linebreaking-characters, followed by a `;`, which is why you got the results you did.

Try this regex instead:

```
MyText.[^ ;]*
```

The `[^ ;]*` matches any character that is not a space or a `;`. If you also don't want tabs or linebreaks to match, you can use the following instead:

```
MyText.[^\s;]*
```

`\s` matches any whitespace character.